# move transform gizmo to selected vertex in edit mode

Tags: modeling

I am having the hardest time just moving one vertex.
The transform gizmo is where the cursor is not the vertex I want to move.
Please help me make it so the gizmo is at the selected point.

Thank you,
J

[image: Gizmo at cursor, need to move it to the median of vertices selected?]

Answer (score 1):

If you hit Shift + S in Edit Mode, you can "snap (the crosshairs 3D) cursor to selected". Then change the center of your rotation to "3D Cursor" using the little figure eight-like icon near the magnet towards the top of your screen. (You can also reach "snap cursor" via Object > Snap > "Cursor to Selected" in Object Mode.) If that doesn't put the gizmo in the middle of all your selected vertices, then you can try Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor in Object Mode.

Incidentally, it looks like you have a mass of vertices selected. Try zooming in really close to select just one vertex.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a vertex off screen and selected. Try ALT+A to deselect everything then select a vertex to see if the gizmo goes where you want.
If the yellow dot is still yellow after pressing ALT+A it's the origin not a vertex.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Select Individual origins in the list here, this will make the gizmo show at your selected vertex.